# Windows Extended Style Bug?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to set short-cut keys for my program so that:

`Win + left` put the window to the left half of the screen (1/2),

then `Win + up` to put it to the upper left of the screen (1/4).

Only `WS_EX_STATICEDGE` (one of the Extended Styles) can achieve it.

> As for the others, either needs to pressed `Win left` twice to be 1/2, or to be 1/4 with only once `Win left`.

But I encountered some very strange situations：

```cpp
hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, "WindowClass", "Caption", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, /* x */
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, /* y */
                        640,             /* width */
                        480,             /* height */
                        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

fprintf(stderr, "EX_STYLE: %#lX  ,  STYLE: %#lX\n", GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE), GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE));
if (SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_STATICEDGE) == 0)
    ErrorExit((LPTSTR)L"SetWindowLongptrW()");
fprintf(stderr, "EX_STYLE: %#lX  ,  STYLE: %#lX\n", GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE), GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE));
```

The output is:

```bash
EX_STYLE: 0X20100  ,  STYLE: 0X14CF0000
EX_STYLE: 0X20000  ,  STYLE: 0X14CF0000
```

`WS_EX_STATICEDGE` is `0x20000`, `WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE` is `0x100`, from MSDN.

The first output should be `0x20000` while the second should be `0x20100`. Why it doesn't?

I have tried `RegisterHotKey()`, which can't register hot key like `Win up` because it has been registered.

All the source code are below for testing.Compile it with mingw-gcc(`gcc main.c -mconsole`).

Besides, `SetWindowPos()` , `ShowWindow()` and `SetWindowLongPtr()` can't correct it.

```c
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

void ErrorExit(LPTSTR lpszFunction)
{
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);

    // Display the error message and exit the process

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
                                      (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
                    LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
                    TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
                    lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(dw);
}

/* This is where all the input to the window goes to */
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {

    /* Upon destruction, tell the main thread to stop */
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    /* All other messages (a lot of them) are processed using default procedures */
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

/* The 'main' function of Win32 GUI programs: this is where execution starts */
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc; /* A properties struct of our window */
    HWND hwnd;     /* A 'HANDLE', hence the H, or a pointer to our window */
    MSG msg;       /* A temporary location for all messages */

    /* zero out the struct and set the stuff we want to modify */
    memset(&wc, 0, sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc; /* This is where we will send messages to */
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    /* White, COLOR_WINDOW is just a #define for a system color, try Ctrl+Clicking it */
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);   /* Load a standard icon */
    wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); /* use the name "A" to use the project icon */

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, "WindowClass", "Caption", WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, /* x */
                        CW_USEDEFAULT, /* y */
                        640,             /* width */
                        480,             /* height */
                        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

fprintf(stderr, "EX_STYLE: %#lX  ,  STYLE: %#lX\n", GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE), GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE));
if (SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE | WS_EX_STATICEDGE) == 0)
    ErrorExit((LPTSTR)L"SetWindowLongptrW()");
fprintf(stderr, "EX_STYLE: %#lX  ,  STYLE: %#lX\n", GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE), GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE));

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    /*
        This is the heart of our program where all input is processed and
        sent to WndProc. Note that GetMessage blocks code flow until it receives something, so
        this loop will not produce unreasonably high CPU usage
    */
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {                           /* If no error is received... */
        TranslateMessage(&msg); /* Translate key codes to chars if present */
        DispatchMessage(&msg);  /* Send it to WndProc */
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: I can't directly set the extended style in `CreateWindowExW()` . Because I need to change the window created with Qt.

Comment: Maybe use WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU  instead of WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW. WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW includes WS_THICKFRAME, which I could believe would interfere with WS_EX_STATICEDGE.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Yes, you're right. But the hot key `Win + Left` won't work (still can't be registered )if I unset WS_EX_THICKFRAME. It's interesting and I will try more.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir  It seems to be a feature of windows. I find some information about it : [https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.vb.winapi/c/x-GNxvYxqFs/m/5uiK_xGoE90J](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.vb.winapi/c/x-GNxvYxqFs/m/5uiK_xGoE90J).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can only successfully set the extended style to `WS_EX_STATICEDGE|WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE` when `CreateWindow()`.

Setting it later by `SetWindowLong()` will cause the system to remove `WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE` automatically.

From "[Does setting WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE actually do anything?](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.vb.winapi/c/x-GNxvYxqFs/m/5uiK_xGoE90J)"

> **Windows 95/98/Me automatically adds and removes the WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE style
> for windows in all applications**. For a version 3.x application, Windows
> 95/98/Me adds the WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE style to a window if, in version 3.1, the
> window would have a dialog border or a sizable border. **Windows 95/98/Me
> removes the WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE style if the window's style changes** so that it
> would no longer have a dialog border or sizable border in version 3.1.
> Windows 95/98/Me uses similar criteria for adding and removing the
> WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE style for a version 4.0 or later application, except that
> any window that has a title bar receives the WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE style,
> regardless of the window's other border styles.